# Xcode 8.3.2 signing errors

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, signing

I have Xcode 8.3.2 on Sierra.  I am trying to build an Enterprise .ipa (have Enterprise membership).

I am having issues signing my app.  Specifically in Xcode I have the following under General\Signing:

- Automatically manage signing is enabled
- Team:  "My Team (Enterprise)"
- Provisioning Profile: Xcode Managed Profile
- Signing Certificate:  iOS Developer
- Status

  - Failed to create provisioning profile "com.myapp" cannot be registered to your development team.  Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
  - No profiles for 'com.myapp' were found.  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.myapp'.

My steps were:

1. Logged into Enterprise account at https://developer.apple.com/account/
2. Under Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles I selected the Add
3. Selected In-House and Ad Hoc
4. On my MAC in the Keychain Access I selected KeyChain Access\Certificate Assistant\Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority
5. Saved to my desktop
6. In https://developer.apple.com/account/ I uploaded the certificate signing request
7. I see it as a certificate as type iOS Distribution with and expiration date
8. I download the .cer file and double click on it to install it
9. Within Xcode\Preferences I find the Team under the Apple ID and under Manage Certificates I see iOS Distribution Certificates and Enterprise with today's date
10. I select the Download All Profiles for that team
11. In Xcode I select General\Signing and "My Team (Enterprise)

At this point I get the two errors described above.

I am new to Xcode development so I am sure there is something wrong with my steps.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are trying to do an enterprise build (In house app distribution), your Signing Certificate should be iOS Distribution.  iOS Development would be for builds to a device (e.g. for debugging)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In Xcode preferences\accounts when I select a team and Manage Certificates button - under iOS Distribution Certificates I see an Enterprise one.  No matter what team I pick under Signing (have automatically manage signing enabled) I always see Signing certificate set to iOS Developer.  Do I need to turn off Automatically manage signing?  I noticed in Build Settings under Signing\Code Signing Identity everything is set to iOS Developer.  I tried setting this to iOS Distribution but it did not help.

Comment: Wait, is your app bundle id in your project actually "com.myapp"? If so, that is likely reserved, or already taken by some other developer account. You need to change your bundle id to something unique to you. A bundle id can only be registered to one dev account. Also, if you are using auto code signing, you shouldn't need to manually create the profile and cert. that's what the auto code signing will do for you. It won't hurt, but it is unnecessary.

Comment: no it is not actually com.myapp.  I have an older MAC with an older version of Xcode that I have built on and deployed to the app store with a unique bundle id.  I am trying to get this working on a new MAC with the latest version of Xcode and am seeing the above errors when trying to build an enterprise version (which I have been able to do on my old setup)

Comment: And you are using the same Apple ID to build on the new Mac as you used to create the original provisioning profile?  If you sign into the dev account and go into the identifiers section do you see the exact bundle id of your app?

Answer (score 9):

Well the solution to my issue was to do the following:

1. In Xcode under the "**General**" tab to **disable**  **Automatically manage signing**
2. At https://developer.apple.com/account in my enterprise account under provisioning profiles I created a new distribution profile
3. Downloaded the profile => .mobileprovision file
4. Double clicked on the .mobileprovision file
5. With **Automatically manage signing** disabled I then selected the Provisioning Profile I just created and downloaded in the drop downs for Signing (Debug) and Signing (Release)
6. At this point I was able to archive and export an enterprise .ipa

Comment: Where did you find the `.mobileprovision` file? Or how did you create it in the first place?

Comment: You did not mention about free developer Program

Comment: downloading .mobileprovision and opening it xcode resolved my signing errors in manually running Xcode and creating archive, which is running on mac laptop but I am not able to trigger the same using jenkins from master running on ubuntu ! does any one have idea on this

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my issue that's similar to this one:

> Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

- Your bundle identifier is already in use by other developers I guess, so just change your **bundle identifier in the Identify tab** right above your **Signing tab** to another one:
- For example:
  Bundle Identifier: org.react.native.example.RamenForLifeIn2022

Hope this helps :)