# Xcode 8.3 signing errors : Failed to create provisioning profile, No profiles for 'com.myapp' were found

Tags: xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I am having issues signing my app. Specifically in Xcode I have the following under General > Signing:

Automatically manage signing is enabled
Team: "My Team "
Provisioning Profile: Xcode Managed Profile
Signing Certificate: iOS Developer
Status
Failed to create provisioning profile "com.myapp" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

No profiles for 'com.myapp' were found. Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.myapp'.

I get the two errors described above.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719507/xcode-8-3-2-signing-errors

Comment: Hope this helps: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AppID.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like changing the "Name" (not the ID) of App ID in developer portal under "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" to the next format "XC com mycompany appname" (in case your app ID was com.mycompany.appname) helps Xcode see your appID. Strange but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my issue that's similar to this one:

> Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

- Your bundle identifier is already in use by other developers I guess, so just change your **bundle identifier in the Identify tab** right above your **Signing tab** to another one:
- For example:
  Bundle Identifier: org.react.native.example.RamenForLifeIn2022

Hope this helps :)